# Http request Unauthorized

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am developing my first web app using angularjs , created a aspx page , added the controller. When I debug in local ASPX page is getting opened and Controller also working fine , but when I call the save function in angular . It is returning the status code as not authorized .

below is the call i have made

```
 $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "Login.aspx/SaveOrganizationName",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { },
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        }).
```

Any suggestion, how to fix ?? I have set the project to run on IIS. as I'm not having enough idea on this , please explain me detailed 
thanks

Comment: This is an authentication issue. The server is telling your client it has not passed the proper credentials to have access to the server object.

Comment: The `dataType` property is not a valid property of the $http config. It is ignored by the $http service.

Comment: You're doing a POST to an ASPX page. You usually make ajax calls to webservices or a REST service. The login aspx page is what will look on UI. Clicking on the login button on this page, then you need to invoke the REST/WEB service using $http via angular.